# sorting chapters in an 4 level array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to sort an existing array into 4 dimension array:
the "list" array that I have:

```
  1 => "text1"
  10 => "text10"
  11 => "text11"
  101 => "text101"
  1011 => "text1011"
  10123 => "text10123" 
  2 => "text2"
  20 => "text20"
  201 => "text201"
  2011 => "text2011"
  20111 => "text20111"
```

the array I want is one that has all the data sorted by each number (in 4 dimention) i mean that i won't have an other array in the end of $chapter[1] containing 10123 => "text10123" (this one will be in the same array as this one :  1011 => "text1011" 
here is an exemple of the array i want

```
$chapter[1] = array(
  1 => "text1", array(
    10 => "text10", 11 => "text11", array(
      101 => "text101", array(
          1011 => "text1011", 10123 => "text10123" )
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Please add more information about your question and also add what you tried.

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You're missing code that doesn't work. if you want your issue to be solved for free, that's not what stack overflow is intended for.

Comment: more precisely: 1. describe the result you need in more detail, the example you shown is not descriptive enough and contains mistakes; 2. show what you have tried; 3. describe how your attempts failed. In this case, the question will be seen as high quality one and other users will be happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use `for-loop` and break each number to digits (with [str-split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)) and then add the arrays.

Consider the following example:

```
$arr = array(1, 11, 111, 113, 2, 21, 211, 213);
$chapter = array(); // this will be your result array

foreach($arr as $e) {
    $digits = str_split($e);
    $current = &$chapter;
    foreach($digits as $d) {
        if (!isset($current[$d]))
            $current[$d] = array();
        $current = &$current[$d];
    }
}
```

Notice I used `&` to assign the new array to the original result one.

I know your array has missing key and not have to be sorted but I guess you can overcome it (filter and sort the array before)

**Edited**

After question has change this is the example code: (when key `DATA` is for the text you want and key `CHILDREN` for the next elements)

```
$arr = array(1 => "text1", 10 => "text10", 11 => "text11", 101 => "text101", 1011 => "text1011", 10123 => "text10123", 2 => "text2", 20 => "text20", 201 => "text201", 2011 => "text2011", 20111 => "text20111");
$chapter = array();

foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
    $digits = str_split(substr($key, 0, 4)); // if 4 digits is the max depth 
    $current = &$chapter;
    foreach($digits as $d) {
        if (!isset($current["CHILDREN"][$d]))
            $current["CHILDREN"][$d] = array();
        $current = &$current["CHILDREN"][$d];
    }
    $current["DATA"] = $val;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but how do you assigne a value to each of the keys 1 will have House for exemple and 111 Car

Comment: What do you mean by assign a value? Can you please update your question with the desire output? Currently its works as posted in your question

Comment: You realize this is **very** different from the original post, right? And key cannot have two values so your desire output not valid - as key "1" cannot have both "text1" and array of the rest - only if they are also encapsulate under array...

Comment: yes i mean they are encapsulate under array. there is an array under an array to be as the ordering of the numbers

Comment: @jason9 edited the answer by your updates - please edit also the title of your question - currently it is not describe the issue

Comment: yes thank you it's almost what i wanted, the thing is you didn't take account of this : array (1011 => "text1011", 10123 => "text10123" ) >> when there is 4 digits and more they must be set into the last array.

Comment: @jason9 then add `substr` to the `str_split` - upodated

Comment: Thank you very much you are just AWESOME :)